# storing timestamp to session and counting time difference causes issues

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am counting how many seconds it takes to go from aspx page 1 to page 2.   This time is not reflecting a real clock.. Where is the bug?

on page 1 I have:

```
Session("sessioncreated") = Now.Ticks
```

on page 2 I  have:

```
Dim diff As Long = 0
If Not Session("sessioncreated") Is Nothing Then
  diff = Now.Ticks - Session("sessioncreated")
End If
Dim timediff As Integer = TimeSpan.FromTicks(diff).Seconds
```

Comment: @Tom: BTW, pop over to your question here:- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/642478/creating-expiring-asp-net-session-value  and clarify your purpose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would help to know what issues you're seeying...
Regardless, I think you should change:

```
Dim timediff As Integer = TimeSpan.FromTicks(diff).Seconds
```

to

```
Dim timediff As Integer = TimeSpan.FromTicks(diff).TotalSeconds
```

Comment: ARGH! How did I not see that. Good catch! That's my all time favorite .NET gotcha.

Answer (score 1):

Use:-

```
Session("sessioncreated") = Now
Dim diff as TimeSpan

If Not Session("sessioncreated") Is Nothing Then
   diff = Now - DirectCast(Session("sessioncreated"), DateTime)
End If
Dim timediff As Integer = diff.TotalSeconds
```

Answer (score 0):

keep it simple

```
    Dim stpw As New Stopwatch 'declare in the class


    'on page 1
    stpw.Reset()
    stpw.Start()


    'on page 2
    stpw.Stop()
    'stpw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds 'will contain seconds between the two
```